# VBA code for copying values from one column to another while keeping the formula of the source cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have just started learning about VBA and I cannot figure out how to copy values from one column to another while keeping the formula of the source column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bGNj.jpg)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Care to share what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copyFormula()
    Sheet1.Columns(3).Formula = Sheet1.Columns(2).Formula
End Sub
```

Try this. Hope it will solve your problem.

Cheers. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Kindly up vote the answer,If it solved ur Problem. :P